# When to use ftp_pasv?

Tags: php, ftp

When should I set ftp_pasv to TRUE? Can I just do that always? If not, is there a way for me to determine programatically if the server requires it?

Comment: Have you heard of google?: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html   OR   http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/what-does-passive-mode-mean/

Comment: The question is not what the difference is between the two. Rather, when connecting to an FTP in PHP, is there a way to determine if I need to set ftp_pasv to TRUE.

Comment: reading over documentation based on FTP will help you decide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`passive mode` and `active mode` are 2 ways to initialize a data connection with the FTP server.

When in `passive mode`, your FTP client ask, with the `PASV` command, a port to connect to the FTP server. The server reply a big number wich is the IP and PORT, the connection could be established (The FTP client - you - initialize the connection)

When in `active mode`, your FTP client tell to the FTP server, with the `PORT` command, which port it should connect (The server initialize the connection).

So, there is not "a way" to determine wich method to use. It depends on your FTP server capabilities and on your situation.

First, you have to check if your FTP server accept both mode, `active` and `passive`.

Secondly, you have to check if you, as a client, are behind a NAT router. If it's the case, then it will be more easy to use passive mode (As this is your FTP client which will initialize the connection). In other case, you will need to make some router configuration...

Programmatically, you can try to initialize data connection with `PASV` and check the server response. Depend on the response code, you should be able to know if you have to switch mode.

Comment: Sounds painful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Passive mode is more commonly available then active mode. You can issue a FEAT command to the FTP server to see if PASV is supported (this will work as long as FEAT command itself is supported).

Generally you have to know upfront if a server 'requires' passive mode. (contact the server administrator to find out if passive mode is supported).